# Browsing an e-mail archive offline

Tags: email, imap, archiving

I've got huge amounts of old e-mails which begin to clutter my IMAP mailbox. I can easily download them all from my account and store them as .mbox files locally, but the question is: How can I browse them after storing them locally? I need to search through them (more or less efficiently.), and occasionally open an attachment. They will be never synchronised again with an online folder. I also don't need the ability to resort/delete/retag etc.

Comment: use any mail client

Comment: Unfortunately, those want you to set up an account usually -- unless there is some offline addon for Thunderbird/etc.?

Answer (score 2):

Try this: [Importing "mbox"](http://kb.wisc.edu/wiscmail/page.php?id=6436)

It gives you instructions on how to import local mbox files into a few different clients. You will then be able to view them.